# Is there any built in django authentication and acl=access controll list library?

Tags: python, django, authentication, acl

Is there any built in django authentication and acl=access controll list library ?

Acl is for allow/deny action/method or resources.

These auth/acl are available in other web framework as built in or as library or as packages/gems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is django.contrib.auth: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/